# Exception running JUnit tests with AndroidStudio: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Parcelable

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit4

I've created unit tests as per http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support, but when I run them I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Parcelable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 33 more
```

Here is a snippet of one of my tests:

```
package com.aadhk.woinvoice.bean;

import com.aadhk.woinvoice.util.Constant;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InvoiceCalculatorTest extends TestCase {
  private static final double EPSILON = 1e-4;

  public void testNoTaxNoDiscount() {
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    List<InvoiceItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    InvoiceItem item = new InvoiceItem();
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.1, with Android Plugin Version 1.1.3 and Gradle version 2.2.1.

My code in question does implement the Parceable interface, but I was hoping there was a way to run these tests.  The tests themselves do not exercise or use Parceable in any way.

Comment: The tests run fine from the command line ./gradlew testFreeDebug --tests='*.InvoiceCalculatorTest'

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know why it fixed. I updated also android studio to 1.3.0 and suddenly I could run the tests again individually. The plugin is also 1.3.0

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into this using IntelliJ, but I'd imagine this would work for Android Studio as well.

I solved the issue by editing the run/debug configuration for my test and checking "Use alternative JRE" and trying a different platform of Android.  I'd recommend trying out different ones and seeing if it resolves the issue.
[image: Test Configuration Screenshot]

Comment: A few years later and it's still applicable. Any idea/theory why this happens?

Comment: If you're using the regular Java sdk to run the test, it won't have Parcelable, since it's only present in the Android sdk. That's why setting an alternative JRE to the android sdk explicitly resolves the issue

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to do this in a library module and it didn't work, no matter what JRE I used, it couldn't load any classes implementing Parcelable. However, I moved my test to the application module, even in the test folder, and the test worked. The run configuration wasn't JUnit's though. It was Gradle's. I don't understand why it works nor why it didn't work before.

Answer (score -1):

As [David Rawson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564479/mockito-in-android-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-android-os-parcelabl#answer-45566253)

> Local Unit Tests run on your laptop or desktop in the JVM there. Hence, they do not have access to the native Android classes like `Parcelable` and if you run a local unit test against a class that uses those methods you will get errors.

So I suggest to put your test class in the path `app/src/androidTest/java/your-project-package/your-test-class` in your project directory. Also make sure to run your test on the device or emulator.