# Mockito in Android error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

The interface is as follows：

```
interface ILoginView{
    fun userResponseProcessor(user: User?)
}
```

I mock the interface in my test class:

```
 @Mock
 private val mMockLoginView:  ILoginView? = null
```

when run this test, An error occurred

```
    Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

        at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:38)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
  ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 75 more
```

How to solve the error?

Comment: the User class is  Parcelable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly please use the correct version of Mockito:

```
androidTestCompile ''org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.47' 
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.47'
```

Secondly, there are two types of tests for an Android project: Local Unit tests and Instrumented Tests. See the [official documentation for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html)

Local Unit Tests run on your laptop or desktop in the JVM there. Hence, they do not have access to the native Android classes like `Parcelable` and if you run a local unit test against a class that uses those methods you will get errors.

At this stage you have two choices, you can run your tests as instrumented tests on a real device or emulator or you can use a framework like [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) which allows you to run local unit tests with all of the native classes like `Parcelable`